# How can I override the ReleasePayments process / process all method?

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to add some custom code to the process of the Release Payments screen.  If I create a customization project and add a Graph extension to the CODE section, I can't find any method with a name similar to  'Release Payments' to override in the list to select from (even though it exists as public in the BLC):

[image]

and if I try to manually code the override, I get an error that it can't find that method.

So basically, my question is, how do I intercept the process on the Release Payments screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success with overriding the `ARReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProc` like below. All the AR documents (invoices, payments, etc.) call the `ARReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProc` during the release and that function does the main process. The below code is basically calling what that function was supposed to do and adding the delegate for when the release is completed.

```
public class ARReleaseProcessExt: PXGraphExtension<ARReleaseProcess>
{
    public static bool IsActive()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void OnReleaseComplete(ARRegister doc)
    {
        try
        {
            if (doc!=null && doc.DocType== ARDocType.Payment)
            {
                ///ADD your code here
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            /// handler errors.
        }
    }
    #region ReleaseDocProc
    public delegate List<ARRegister> ReleaseDocProcDelegate(JournalEntry je, ARRegister ardoc, List<Batch> pmBatchList, ARDocumentRelease.ARMassProcessReleaseTransactionScopeDelegate onreleasecomplete);

    [PXOverride]
    public List<ARRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, ARRegister ardoc, List<Batch> pmBatchList, ARDocumentRelease.ARMassProcessReleaseTransactionScopeDelegate onreleasecomplete, ReleaseDocProcDelegate del)
    {
        onreleasecomplete += OnReleaseComplete;
        return del(je, ardoc, pmBatchList, onreleasecomplete);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The override is a little different in case of AP module as the signature of the function is different there.

```
  public class APReleaseProcess_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APReleaseProcess>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDelegate(JournalEntry je, APRegister doc, Boolean isPrebooking, ref List<INRegister> inDocs);
    [PXOverride]
    public List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, APRegister doc, Boolean isPrebooking, ref List<INRegister> inDocs, ReleaseDocProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      var retVal = baseMethod(je,doc,isPrebooking,ref inDocs);
      //Your code goes here.
      PXTrace.WriteInformation("My override worked!");
      return retVal;
    }


    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: But the Release Payments is in AP, right?  Can I just substitute AP for AR in your example?

Comment: For the record, there is no APDocumentRelease.APMassProcessReleaseTransactionScopeDelegate... or anything similar to your AR example

Comment: @pmfith didn't realize that you were talking about AP Payments. The AP Payments' release is organized the same way, but the ReleaseDocProc doesn't have any delegate parameters, so you will need to call the Base Method and then add your code before returning the list of the APRegisters. I have added the example to my answer